# PhpStorm, set a custom coding standard

Tags: wordpress, phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, phpcs, phpcodesniffer

I have a dockerized WSL with PHP code sniffer installed. Now I stuck to set up "wordpress" coding standard.
When I run `phpcs -i` from WSL it then shows

> The installed coding standards are PSR2, PEAR, PSR12, MySource, Squiz,
> Zend, PSR1, WordPress-Core, WordPress-Docs, WordPress-Extra and
> WordPress

but the "coding standards" in the settings are still Pear, PSR1, PSR12, PSR2, Squiz, Zend, Custom. How to make it understand that I have WordPress coding standard?

Comment: of course Phpstorm was restarted since then

Comment: `installed_paths` -- does it points to the right folder? In the config file and/or the IDE ("Installed standards path" field)? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-66502/Custom-CodeSniffer-ruleset-cannot-locate-dependencies.#focus=Comments-27-6057182.0-0

Comment: Yepp, installed_paths does, but when I manually set "installed standard path" it says phpcs: ERROR: the file "\set\path" does not exists. But Phpstorm looks for a file here not a directory - while this dialog enables only directories....

Comment: *"ERROR: the file "\set\path" does not exists. But Phpstorm looks for a file here not a directory"* I'm not sure at all .. but it could be affected by "dockerized WSL" -- not using the path on the target file system... TBH -- I do not use PHP_CS that much, only local (Windows host OS, nothing like Docker/WSL or remote) and standard rules only (which works perfectly fine for me) and therefore cannot generate many ideas for your setup.